# What does for item in list loop represent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

In the for loop `for item in lists` does the `item` represent the current index, as with the `for i in range()` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the syntax `for a in b...`, a is always assigned to each item in `b`. Thus, `i` in `for i in range(x)` is only being assigned to each item in the list produced by `range(x)`.

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> range(5) 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for item in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
...     print item
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>>
```

#### Thus, `item` represents each item in the list.

Comment: So in `for item in list` `item` represents each item in list while in `for i in range` `i` represents the indices? Does this make the `i in range` eligible for being modified (e.g. `list[i] += 1`) which is impossible with the `for item in list?`

Comment: No, in `for i in range`, `i` represents each item in the **list** produced by the `range(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements),

> The `for` statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as C), **Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.** For example (no pun intended):
>
> ```
> >>> # Measure some strings:
> ... words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
> >>> for w in words:
> ...     print w, len(w)
> ...
> cat 3
> window 6
> defenestrate 12
> ```

In your case, when you are using `range`, `item` represents the individual items in the list of numbers returned by `range`.

Answer (score 0):

In english it's just like `for every item in list`. Some other languages use `for each` to show this.